# Magento additional weight

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento ver. 1.6.1.0
I'd like to add 8lbs to each order (packing materials)

Can't find something useful in Google for "additional weight magento"

How to do this? Is there any backend option or any coding solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I hard-coded that.
That's NOT the finest solution ever, but at least it works.

NOTICE: We use ONLY FedEx there, so this works ONLY for that.

In app/code/Core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php find something like this, line 359:

```
'Value' => $r->getWeight()
```

Here's the weight in Lbs. I've added 8 here. 
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -1):

Do it in your shipping module. This depends on what module you are using, however, you can just add to the total with a single line of code, even edit the system.xml for packing materials weight so you can adjust it. That will be vastly simpler than Ayman's solution, which I think is for a different problem.

Comment: Is it this one? \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\etc\system.xml I can't find where to add the weight